# Rails 4 - Activerecord support for OR condition in queries that use WHERE

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements, where-clause

Does ActiveRecord supports the use of the OR condition in the WHERE clause while using a hash or array?  For example, if I wanted to retrieve the ages of anybody named Gary, John, OR Carlos, how could I write the query?

Here's the code:

```
 params[:names] = ["Gary", "John", "Carlos"]
 @ages = People.select("age").where('name = ?', params[:names])
```

Because params[:names] could contain any number of items, I'd rather avoid hardcoding the query with a fixed number of OR conditions.

I have looked at the squeel gem but is that the best solution for this?

Comment: Did you try: `@ages = People.select("age").where(name: params[:names])`? That should generate a SQL `IN` clause and accomplish this as well.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach - That's exactly what I needed!  Thanks so much!  BTW - do you want to post the solution?  I will upvote and accept your answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Rails' built-in SQL `IN` clause support instead of chaining `OR` clauses. The following should work:

```
@ages = People.select("age").where(name: params[:names])
```

This generates a query like:

```
SELECT age FROM people WHERE name IN ("Gary", "John", "Carlos")
```